# ErrorsMetricbeat and collectd while monitoring network IO

Tags: kibana-4, elastic-stack, system-administration, collectd, network-monitoring

Recently i tried Metricbeat and collectd to collect network I/O per seconds but all those program give me an accumulated data .
Also i have tried ntopng which is good and give me the necessary data but it send data every 5min and this is a large period.
So is there any suggestion on how to monitor network I/O using ELK?
or how to change the period of sending data to ES in ntopng?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The kibana timelion cant be used to get the network throughput from collectd or metricbeat.

E.g. of timelion query for collectd:

```
.es(index=collectd*, q="plugin:\"interface\" AND if_octets", metric="avg:tx", timefield="@timestamp").divide(1000).fit(carry).derivative().fit(average)
```

This results in graph: 
[Network output Mbytes per interval configured at collectd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcCd5.png)

Same applies for metricbeat:

```
.es(index=metricbeat*, q="network",metric="avg:system.network.out.bytes", timefield="@timestamp").divide(1000).fit(carry).derivative().fit(average)
```

If you need to query some particular interface or host, you need just update the query.

More info about timelion query syntax [is here](https://github.com/elastic/timelion/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.md).